# How to know whether an installed package is being used or not?

Tags: package

I need to check whether an installed package is being used or not in my sandbox rather than clicking on "Where is this used?".

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "being used"? Do you mean which users have access to it?

Comment: I need to remove a detail page link which is in a package. In order to delete that, how to do ?

Comment: That is a pretty different question. You can't delete a managed package detail page link but you can remove it from the layout. Is that sufficient?